# Sort and associate objects with unique identifier in a collection

Tags: java, generics

I'm working my through an assignment and got stuck on step 5, would appreciate any help.

1. Carefully study the class structure in Products.java.
2. Design a generic container called GenericOrder that acts as a collection of an arbitrary number of objects in Products.java. Design a mechanism that gives each instance of the container a unique identifier. Implement as many methods as necessary. You must use Java generics features.
3. Design and implement a subclass of GenericOrder called ComputerOrder that takes an arbitrary number of different classes of ComputerPart objects, Peripheral objects, and Service objects. Implement as many methods as necessary.
4. Design and implement a subclass of GenericOrder called PartyTrayOrder that takes an arbitrary number of different classes of Cheese objects, Fruit objects, and Service objects. Implement as many methods as necessary.
5. Design and implement a class called OrderProcessor. You must implement at least the following methods:

   - accept; // this method accepts a GenericOrder or any of its subclass objects and stores it in any internal collection of OrderProcessor.
   - process; // this method sorts all accepted orders in the internal collection of GenericOrder into collections of ComputerPart, Peripheral, Cheese, Fruit, and Service. You must associate each object with the unique identifier. You may refer to the TwoTuple.java example in the text book.
   - dispatchXXX; // this method simulates the dispatch of the sorted collections. For example, the method dispatchComputerParts() should produce this output:

     - Motherboard name=Asus, price=$37.5, order number=123456
     - Motherboard – name=Asus, price=$37.5, order number=987654
     - RAM – name=Kingston, size=512, price=$25.0, order number=123456
6. Create a client class to test OrderProcessor. You will need to create a datagenerator for testing purpose. It is not mandatory but you may use a variation of Data Generator in TIJ pages 637 to 638.

Here is what I have for Q5

```
public abstract class OrderProcessor<T> {
    private ArrayList<T> dataCollection = new ArrayList<T>();

    public void accept(T item){
        dataCollection.add(item);
    }

    public void process(){
        Collections.sort(dataCollection);
    }

    public List getDataCollection(){
        return dataCollection;
    }
}
```

In its current state `Collections.sort(dataCollection);` doesn't compile because it does not accept `T` and if I change the ArrayList to `String` any function used from other subclasses won't work because they all `T`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Firstly, an `OrderProcessor` isn't an order. It shouldn't extend `GenericOrder`.

Comment: Secondly, the description doesn't say that `OrderProcessor` needs to be generic: it just says that `accept` should accept a `GenericOrder`. So, make it accept a `GenericOrder`.

Comment: yeah sorry about the extend part I was trying different things and must have forgotten to delete it

Comment: You could call the `stream` method on your `dataCollection` and then use the [`groupingBy`][1] collector to group by identifier. [1]: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Since you want to partition your orders and not sort, you can use something like this:

```
dataCollection.stream().collect(
  Collectors.groupingBy(order -> order.getIdentifier())
)
```

Here, this groups them by their identifiers and puts them into a `Map`. The `order.getIdentifier()` part is just a placeholder for whatever you want to use to divide them up. The return type will be `Map<TypeOfIdentifier, T>`.

For this to work, though, your `T` has to be of some specific type (`T extends Product` perhaps?) so you can get the identifier. Since I don't know the code for differentiating between different products, I can't put the exact code here.

The Javadoc for [`Collectors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html)

---

This is why Collections.sort wasn't working for you, but you don't need Collections.sort anyways.

T must extend the [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, because obviously you can't sort objects of just any type. The Comparable interface has a `compareTo` method that lets you sort.

An alternative would be to write a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that defines a single method: `compare`, which would take 2 objects of type `T` and return an `int` representing the order (in most cases it's basically the first argument minus the second argument). For this, you would need to use `Collections.sort(dataCollection, customComparator)`.

You can define your comparator with a lambda expression, but I can't help you beyond that because I have no idea how you want to sort your objects.

Comment: I think "sort" in the rubric is misleading. It's not really "sorting" as much as "partitioning", I think.

Comment: I'll try to clarify everything a bit. I think it is more as "partitioning" as you said because basically the accept method has to accept all the objects coming from GenericOrder and it subclasses and process() will "sort" them into containers or array so they can output different thing.

Comment: Would there be a way to tackle the problem using tuples since they suggest using them but I wasn't able to get it to work early on so I settled for `Collections.sort`

Comment: @user Just to double check the getIdentifier() mathod i replace with a method that will differenciate between the object so they can be sorted

Comment: well all the products are subclasses so I think `getClass()` will work.

Comment: @user is there a way to test if process is working there are no error but just want to check that its doing what it should do

Comment: @user sorry kind of a dumb question but do I keep the method as void? shouldn't there be a return statment?

Comment: @dxbh0517 Yeah, it should have a return statement. You're returning a `Map<Class, Product>` or something like that, right?